# Java if statement to change a variable value

Tags: java

I've just started with Java, roughly done 5-6 hours but I have no idea how to approach this task.

I'm doing a tax system for a hotel.
A standard rate of tax is used (20%).
However, the program asks the user if they want to change this rate by asking the user to input "Yes" or "No", if yes, proceed to enter the new value of the variable `tax`, if no, it keeps the standard rate of (20%).

There's a lot more to the task. However, this is the only issue I'm struggling with.

Can anyone tell me how to write such an if statement? I have absolutely no idea how to do it with such specific user input.

Any sort of help or suggestions would be appreciate so I can play around with it.

Comment: What have you tried doing so far? And what is the exact problem? Do you not know how to get user input? Or do you not now how to compare strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can find the solution within the following example. 
Please note that it's just a quick and dirty example without any errorhandling or gui.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Demo {

private int rate;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Demo demo =  new Demo();
    demo.work();

}

private void work()
{
    rate = 20;
    System.out.println("Would you like to use default tax?");
    if (!getInput().equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
    {
        System.out.println("Please set the new rate");
        rate = Integer.parseInt(getInput());
    }
    System.out.println("the rate is "+rate);
}

private String getInput()
{
    String result =  null;

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        result = reader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

}
```

Comment: Worked perfect.
Thanks for the help. All I needed was

System.out.println("Would you like to use default tax?");
    if (!getInput().equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
    {
        System.out.println("Please set the new rate");
        rate = Integer.parseInt(getInput());
    }

I'm going ahead on the coursework, some of the content we haven't learned as of yet. Thanks for letting me know how to do it, be very useful for the feature. Appreciated.